# Passing Array of Structs to a Function as a Pointer (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am attempting to write a function that will initialize all values of N structs in an array. I chose to use a void function and use a structure pointer. I have no issue with using single structure pointers, but I cannot figure out how to pass a pointer address to an array of structs to my function.

The following code produces a single error.

```
typedef struct candidate {
    char name[20]; //name of the election candidate
    int votes; //amount of votes the candidate has
} election;

void Initialize(FILE *fp, int candidates, election *electionCandidates[]);

int main(void)
{
    const int candidates = 7; //this will be the amount of structs initialized
    const int voters = 365; //this will be the N iterations of a for loop for the voting process

    FILE *fp = fopen ("elections.txt", "R"); //save file pointer for use when taking formatted input

    election electionCandidates[candidates]; //declare 'candidates' structs, one for each candidate in the election

    Initialize(fp, candidates, &electionCandidates); //save candidate names and set votes = to 0

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void Initialize(FILE *fp, int candidates, election *electionCandidates[]) //init values of the candidate struct array by passing pointer to void function
{
    int eN = 0, N = candidates; //eN = executed number of for loop iterations, N = total number of iterations to be completed
    for (eN = 0; eN < N; eN ++)
    {
        char name[20] = "";
        fscanf (fp, "%s", &name);
        strcpy(electionCandidates[eN]->name, name);
        electionCandidates[eN]->votes = 0;
    }
}
```

The error I have points to this line:

```
Initialize(fp, candidates, &electionCandidates); //save candidate names and set votes = to 0
```

Does anyone have advice on how to fix my syntax, or a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because you have a pointer to an array and you treat it as an array of pointers inside `Initialize`.

In your case you can simply pass a simple pointer:

```
void Initialize(FILE *fp, int candidates, election *electionCandidates) //init values of the candidate struct array by passing pointer to void function
{
    int eN = 0, N = candidates; //eN = executed number of for loop iterations, N = total number of iterations to be completed
    for (eN = 0; eN < N; eN ++)
    {
        char name[20] = "";
        fscanf (fp, "%s", &name);
        strcpy(electionCandidates[eN].name, name);
        electionCandidates[eN].votes = 0;
    }
}
```

The call from main will become:

```
    Initialize(fp, candidates, electionCandidates); //save candidate names and set votes = to 0
```

Comment: Changing `char name[20] = "";` to `char *name = malloc(20)` and `fscanf (fp, "%s", &name);` to `fscanf (fp, "%s", &name)` is also a good idea. Please include it in your answer.

Comment: Thanks! This compiles and should work. Have not tested it with an input file yet. Looks like I over complicated it by throwing in all the pointer syntax I remember without knowing when to use it. Will need to brush up on that. :B

Answer (score 2):

Passing arrays use a pointer to first item in it, which is the array name already.
First change your function declaration from:

```
void Initialize(FILE *fp, int candidates, election *electionCandidates[]);
```

to

```
void Initialize(FILE *fp, int candidates, election *electionCandidates);
```

and call it like that:

```
Initialize(fp, candidates, electionCandidates);
```

Another thing is that you access members of struct items in an array as it is array of pointers. Use `.` operator instead.

That is what you should do to make it works. Now I'll tell you what've you done:

- `election *electionCandidates[]` in a function declaration is a pointer to a pointer of type `election`
- `&electionCandidates` in your main function is an address to a pointer of type `election`

And in your function body `electionCandidates` is a pointer to an array not an array, that's why if you want access an element of the array you should call something like:

```
(*electionCandidates)[eN].name
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation! I was definitely wondering where I went wrong. I thought that when I set up a pointer as an argument, I would have to feed it a pointer address when I called the function, whereas what I really needed to do was give it the thing to point to.

Definitely feeling like I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
election electionCandidates[candidates];
```

is an array of `election` struct type. For array you do not need to explicitly pass by reference like you are doing:

```
Initialize(fp, candidates, &electionCandidates);
```

Just do this:

```
Initialize(fp, candidates, electionCandidates);
```

In C arrays are automatically passed by reference.